# Joining 6 .stl files together to make 1 file to go to a comercial printer

Tags: modeling, import, properties, 3d-printing

Firstly let me say I have never used Blender before so I'm a total innocent. 
I have 6 .stl files for 2 Pi camera housings made up of 2 and 4 files each.
I have been told if I can incorporate the files into 1 or 2 it will make the process much cheaper,as I'm using a commercial print company. So my question is can I start a new project, import each file individually and join them together to make 1 .stl file.

Comment: My guess is all you need to do is import all STL files into the same Blender scene and reexport them into a single STL file all together. Making them cheaper probably requires some optimization so it consumes less material and prints faster. Having objects close together laying down as as not to stack up very high vertically, will also probably print faster. Not sure if print time is taken into account or not, but if it does it may well save a few bucks.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I'll follow the tutorial below which is roughly as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.   Use Blender to import and position all of your stl files.

Group select all of the objects (so that they are highlighted).
[image]

Use Object -> Join to make all of the individual items one object. The Object menu option appears at the lower left of the Object Mode screen -- if you are in Edit or another mode, you won;t see it...
[image]

Making sure the object is highlighted, use File -> Export -> Stl
[image]

You'll end up with an STL composed of multiple non-connected parts. Whether this is cheaper or not is an issue for your printer: It might take as long to rip and print, and will certainly require the same amount of material to output -- infact, maybe more.... since I am not sure whether the method you are using will add supports or connected sprues between the separate items that were originally the separate stls... But this process will give you an stl with multiple 'pieces'.

Shout if I can assist.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed tutorial I'll follow it to the letter looks like this is  what I need. All the stls are for the finished component no spruces. Again thanks Bill

Comment: Well that was easy took about 10 min to do I'll send the file off and see if that's what they want or if I need to insert spruces. If I need to insert them I might be shouting out to you again....Cheers Bill

Comment: Just to let you know this saved me 1/3 from the original quote so thank you again

Comment: Glad to hear it!  3d printing is an amazing tool for designers, and Blender handles it so well...